# How can I webscrape information in the html element and save it to an Excel row using Beautifulsoup and any excel writer(Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, pandas.excelwriter

I'm new to python and I'm doing it for my project. Can someone help me save it to an excel file?.

This is needed for multiple site URLs so need to add each information into new rows in excel. Sample HTML code is attached below. Please help me on saving it to excel rows and columns and how to iterate it using for loop.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: [SL No ,Job Title, Company Name, Posted on, Closing on, Location, Description, Skills, Link Email ] all these information in an excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you just use `openpyxl` directly rather than via Pandas, this would give you much greater control over how your Excel file would be formatted.

Here is how you could build up multiple row in an Excel file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import Workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

website_url = "https://www.example.com/"
res = requests.get(website_url, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
Links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "jobTitleLink"},)
url = [tag.get('href') for tag in Links]
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

# Write a header row
columns = [
    ("SL No", 10),
    ("Job Title", 25),
    ("Company Name", 20),
    ("Posted on", 13),
    ("Closing on", 13),
    ("Location", 20),
    ("Description", 40),
    ("Skills", 70),
    ("Link Email", 30),
]

thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'), right=Side(
    style='thin'), top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin'))
ws = wb.active

for col_number, (value, width), in enumerate(columns, start=1):
    ws.cell(column=col_number, row=1, value=value).border = thin_border
    ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_number)].width = width

row_number = 2

# get the first link in the entire page
# get value of the href attribute

for x in url[1:5]:
    res = requests.get(f'https://www.example/com/{x}', verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    data = []

    for div_block in soup.find_all('div', class_='block', style=None):
        data.append([line.strip() for line in div_block.stripped_strings])

    li_fr = soup.find('li', class_="fr")
    company_name = li_fr.a.text
    location = list(li_fr.find_next_sibling('li').stripped_strings)[1]

    # Write a data row
    row = [
        '',  # SL No
        data[0][0],  # Job title
        company_name,  # Company name
        data[1][1],
        data[2][1],
        location,
        data[4][1],
        '\n'.join(data[5][1:]),
        data[3][1],
    ]

    for col_number, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
        cell = ws.cell(column=col_number, row=row_number, value=value)
        cell.border = thin_border
        cell.alignment = Alignment(wrapText=True)

    row_number += 1

wb.save('output.xlsx')
print('Saved all the data')
```

This would give you an Excel sheet looking like:

[image: Excel screenshot]

With extra work you can apply any styling you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. I need to write everything in excel (using a loop). When I try to do getting some errors. how to fix that too. please help me .

Comment: I think the HTML in your question does not contain enough data to show how the second (or more) data is. Can you [edit] it to include it or give the URL for where the data was sourced from

Comment: attached the required code, please help me add additional rows to it@Martin Evans

Comment: I have update it to show how to write multiple rows, hope this is helpful

Comment: Actually, I cant write the Sl.No, Company Name, Location. Could you please help me with that?  I'm new in python, I'm just catching everything.

Comment: What is "SL No" ?

Comment: No problem we got the answer. It was serial number. You did a great job

Comment: How to handle if any of data[x][y] is not present? 
Martin Evans

Comment: I suggest you add a test that `data` has the correct number of elements. If it does not I suggest you print it (and skip creating `row`) that way you can analyse which items are missing and build a different `row` perhaps with `N/A` elements

Comment: Is it possible to save the column as blank instead of skipping the row?

Comment: Is it possible to write if else inside  row = [
        '',  # SL No
        data[0][0],  # Job title
        company_name,  # Company name
        data[1][1],
        data[2][1],
        location,
        data[4][1],
        '\n'.join(data[5][1:]),
        data[3][1],
    ]

Comment: As I said you need to determine what is missing in `data` e.g. `if len(data) == ???` then normal else create your alternative `row`. You need to first print failing rows

Comment: Perhaps you could tell me a `job-detail?cmpid=10534&vacancy_id=41129` that fails?